# using yq to get keys and a specific value without knowing key names

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a .yml file structured like this

```
key_1:
   some_other_key
   owners: value
key_2:
   some_other_key
   owners: value
key_3:
   some_other_key
   owners: value
```

I am trying to get the top level key and the value of owners so the output is like

```
key_1, owners.value
key_2, owners.value
key_3, owners.value
```

Is there a way to do this with yq?

Comment: Your input is invalid YAML and your output, while valid YAML, is a multiline scalar. You can neither process invalid YAML with yq nor can you instruct it where to place line breaks in a multiline scalar.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the transformation with a oneliner.

Using [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (Python version)
`yq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value.owners)"'`

Using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (Go version)
`yq e 'to_entries | .[] | .key + ", " + .value.owners'`

#### input

```yaml
key_1:
   some_other_key: other_value
   owners: value_1
key_2:
   some_other_key: other_value
   owners: value_2
key_3:
   some_other_key: other_value
   owners: value_3
```

#### output

```
key_1, value_1
key_2, value_2
key_3, value_3
```